# How to connect to a local idIRCServer

Tags: delphi, indy

Well I have create a project which uses idIRCClient to connect to an IRC server and get responses from the server using that code

```
    with ircClient do
if (edt1.text<>'') and (edt2.text<>'') and (edt3.text<>'')  then
 try
 Host:=edt1.Text;
 port:=StrToIntDef(edt2.Text,6667);
 Nickname:=edt3.Text;
 Username:=edt4.Text;
 Connect;
  except
 if not Connected then
  MessageDlg('Error',mtError,[],0);
 end
 else
 MessageDlg('fill all the fields',mtInformation,[],0);
```

well when I use a host like "ix1.undernet.org" with port 6667 I get responses and a welcome message and I can send c2c private messages , whereas when I create an other module which contains idIRCServer and make it active then connect to it using host='localhost' and port=6667 , I get connected but I don't get any response from the server nor a welcome message even if it is set withing the Greeting Property

Thanks in advance

Comment: As I already stated yesterday: "*Please show your actual code and component properties, or provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating the problem in action. You are obviously doing something wrong, but we can't see what you are actually doing.*" Why did you open a new question that is basically just a duplicate of your [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33508953/)?